# How to change some random elements of an array

Tags: ruby

I want to alter one or more elements of an array randomly. For example, with original array:

```
original = ['john', '124 Gore st', 20, 'manager']
```

After change:

```
new_array = ['johnz', '124 Gore st', 'hall22', 'manager']
```

I did this:

```
x = %w(hello there world)
x.collect! { |element|
  random_ele = x.sample
  (element == random_ele) ? "newele" : element
}
puts x.to_s
```

It's working. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: This could create duplicates. Are you trying to randomly re-order the array?

Comment: If you're trying to replace a random *portion* of the array with other values there is a better way, it just depends on your intent.

Comment: `puts  x.to_s` is redundant because `puts` is one of many Ruby situations that call `.to_s` for you. Try `puts 0`, to see it in action. You probably want `p x`, which is the equivalent of `puts x.inspect`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace just a portion of the entries:

```
require 'securerandom'

def swaperoo(array, factor)
  array.map do |e|
    if (SecureRandom.rand < factor)
      yield
    else
      e
    end
  end
end
```

Like you can do this:

```
original = ['john', '124 Gore st', 20, 'manager']

swaperoo(original, 0.1) do
  'hall%d' % SecureRandom.rand(1..100)
end
```

Comment: How this change the array ? I did put original, nothing happened, I did puts  swaperoo(original, 0.1) do
  'hall%d' % SecureRandom.rand(1..100)
end  nothing happened.

Comment: This solution doesn't modify the original. It returns a new array. If you want to modify the original, you can use `map!` instead of `map`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I meant to mention that. It's generally a bad habit to get into to manipulate in-place in a method, you're damaging someone else's input, but if that's the intent then a `map!` call will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
array = ['john', '124 Gore st', 20, 'manager']
array[rand(array.size - 1)] = "random change"
array
=> ["random change", "124 Gore st", 20, "manager"]
```